# Default Parameters in DotNetNuke 5.6.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

Can we use methods with default parameters in DotNetNuke v5.6.8? I tried compiling my project with .NET v4.0. and it pointed to the methods with default parameter. Please help.

Comment: You should post an example of what isn't working. You also really should check out DNN 7, DNN 5 is far too old and unsupported, bugs, security issues, etc.